# Accessing YouTube API in Meteor project for logged in user

Tags: meteor, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client, youtube-analytics-api

I'm working on a new Meteor project which involves users logging into the site using their Google accounts through OAuth (I'm using the Meteor accounts-google package for this) and when signing in I need them to be able to see some data from the YouTube Analytics API for their YouTube channel. As of now the data I am trying to get is their total daily views, which I then hope to display on a chart for a specified time period.

I have added the following scopes to my accounts-google login system:

```
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
        requestPermissions: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'],
        requestOfflineToken: true,
        forceApprovalPrompt: true,
        loginStyle: "popup"
    });
```

This all seems to be working very well, once a user signs into the site and grants the site access to these I can then see the necessary info in my MongoDB database. Under user.services.google I can now see it has accessToken, idToken, expiresAt, refreshToken, etc.

I've also decided to use the [google api nodejs client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) by implementing it through the meteorhacks:npm package for Meteor. I am using this to refresh tokens (as seen in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32767797) I found helpful).

Using the ["Try It"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/data_model#try-it) API Explorer on the YouTube Analytics API Documentation page, I can get the type of data I'm looking for through this request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2015-10-01&end-date=2015-10-31&metrics=views&dimensions=day&sort=-day&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Now is where I've been completely stuck and really unsure of where to go from here. How can I implement this into my site? I've tried for quite some time now to make this work but everything I attempt isn't working, and there's no real direction. If anyone is willing to help out I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm fairly new to Meteor/JS/APIs so any information/examples is extremely appreciated, especially noob friendly stuff! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [percolate:google-api](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api) package to handle my API call.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use a method and the http package: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http

Looking at the doc you provide, you may try something like this:

Define your method on the server side

```
// server-side
Meteor.methods({
  getYoutubeReports: function(channelId, accessToken, params) {
    params.ids = "channel=="+ channelId;
    params.key = accessToken;
    return HTTP.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports", {
      params: params
    });
  }
});
```

You can then call it on the client side with the data you get from your the authentication (ie. `CHANNEL_ID_OF_MY_USER` & `ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_USER`)

```
// client-side
var reports,
    myParams = {
      "start-date": "2015-10-01",
      "end-date": "2015-10-31",
      "metrics": "views",
      "dimensions": "day",
      "sort": "-day"
    };

Meteor.call('getYoutubeReports', CHANNEL_ID_OF_MY_USER, ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_USER, params, function(error, result) {
  // store or do stuff with the result of the HTTP request here
  console.log(result);
});
```

Feel free to custom `myParams` as your user need!

And if you want to some more tips about how to use HTTP request (really useful to call external API), The Meteor Chef wrote a really good article about it : https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-http-package/

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I'm definitely going to be giving this a try and hopefully I can get it to work! I just have one question, what would be the best way to have it input the "CHANNEL_ID_OF_MY_USER" and "ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_USER"? As of now I see the access token is stored in services.google.accessToken. Channel ID doesn't appear to be stored anywhere in 'users', but I'm guessing I can get that saved to the users profile somehow as well. I'm just unsure of how to have it input this data in the Meteor.call?

Comment: I have tried to use Publish/Subscribe for this but cant' seem to get it to work.. I have this in my server.js: 

Meteor.publish("access_token", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {'services.google.accessToken': 1}});
 }); // Then I Subscribe in Client by: Meteor.subscribe("access_token"); // and then I try to replace "ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_USER" with "access_token" but it doesn't seem to work at all.. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong or how I could achieve something like this?

Comment: Hi @U54! The subscription gives you _the right to access the data_ you published. So you have to do sth like that `let user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()})` where you want to get the data and to get access to your token use this variable : `user.services.google.accessToken`.

Comment: And to answer your first question, your access token is being stored in users collections when they are signing up to your app. Considering the channel id, you should create en event handler with a form to ask them to type their channel id, and then call the method with the value of the input! Here is a really nice tutorial which will help you to go through the basics of Meteor: http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/