# Meteor Google oAuth to refresh accessToken without re-login

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, meteor-accounts

This is my first post.  I will try and be complete.  I am creating a app in Meteor which uses google oAuth.  I am using the following packages:

```
accounts-ui
accounts-google
service-configuration
google-config-ui
```

In my login.js I have:

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #googleLoginButton': function() {
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle(
      { requestPermissions: ['email', 'profile'],
      requestOfflineToken: 'true'
      }
     );
  }
});
```

I get the following in mongo:

```
db.users.find({}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : "9TjGEjEj4ocFhwHtS",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-11T17:38:07.400Z"),
    "services" : {
        "google" : {
            "accessToken" : "ya29.-REDACTED-T9z",
            "idToken" : "eyJhbGcj-REDACTED-LTg",
            "scope" : [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
            ],
            "id" : "107113228066746203535",
            "email" : "XXXXXXy@XXXX.com",
            "verified_email" : true,
            "name" : "XXX XXX",
            "given_name" : "XXX",
            "family_name" : "XXX",
            "picture" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg",
            "locale" : "en",
            "gender" : "male",
            "refreshToken" : "1/HG-REDACTED-oLq0USutc"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2017-10-11T21:47:38.471Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "2lmOK-REDACTED-ptAyDnWo="
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "XXX XXX"
    }
}
```

In the Server/init.js I have: (I am passing the google project info via settings.json)

```
configureGoogle = function(config) {
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
        service: "google"
    });

    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
        service: "google",
        clientId: googleConfig.clientId,
        secret: googleConfig.secret
    });
    return;
};

if (googleConfig) {
    console.log('Got settings for google', googleConfig)
    configureGoogle(googleConfig);
}
```

So things seem to be working.  I can login / out and when I login I get new tokens.  I use the **accessToken** for api calls in other places.  The problem I have is that after a hour the token expires and the API calls start to fail.

I would like to refresh the **accessToken** just before it expires and cant seem to figure out how.  I would also like to force a logout after 24 hours so the token does not refresh forever.

Any assistance if appreciated.

Comment: I think this was already answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764769/meteor-accounts-google-token-expires

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor accounts-google Token Expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764769/meteor-accounts-google-token-expires)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update #1**

Thanks to  Derek Brown below for pointing me in the right direction.  That got me to looking for a meteor google api.  I found this one:  [percolate:google-api](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/google-api)

and according to it doc it does what I was looking for:

> If the user's access token has expired, it will transparently call the exchangeRefreshToken method to get a new refresh token.

I then ran into a error where the **expiresAt** Didnt exist in my mongodb and things were not working.  I then found this post:  [Google-API](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api/issues/16) which suggested:

server/publish.js

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, { fields: { 
    'services.google.accessToken': 1, 
    'services.google.expiresAt': 1 
  }});
});
```

I also made one change from code above:
client/login.js

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #googleLoginButton': function() {
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle(
      { requestPermissions: ['email', 'profile'],
      requestOfflineToken: 'true',
      forceApprovalPrompt: 'true' //<==== This is the change
      }
     );
  }
});
```

This added with no additional code changed this added the **expiresAt** and populated it.

Im doing final testing now. I will update.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Adding forceApprovalPrompt did not help. Did you find anything else about this issue?